# how do i start the "help and support" application in the windows start menu using vb net 2012

Tags: vb.net, startmenu

When I click on "help and support" in the windows 7 start menu, the helpPane.exe program runs. But when I run helpPane.exe, nothing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: [IShellDispatch.Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537718(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: It is a one-liner: CreateObject("Shell.Application").Help()

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, It probably will work!

```
    Dim appData As String = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
    Dim helpSupportPath As String = appData & "\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Maintenance\Help.lnk"
    Process.Start(helpSupportPath)
```